# in mongo need to join two collections using Identity columns and emit the needed columns from both collections

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

I have book and author collection.in this name and works_written are the same value column respectively.so i tried the following script but it emit only first map values,second map values not emitted.

```
book = function() {
emit(this.id, {name: this.name,editions:this.editions});
 }
author = function() {
emit(this.id, {name:this.name,works_written: this.works_writtten,});
 }


r_b = function(k, values) {
var result = {};
values.forEach(function(value) {
    var name;
    for (name in value) {
        if (value.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
             result[name] = value[name];
        }
    }
 });
 return result;
 };
 r_a = function(k, values) {
 var result = {};
 values.forEach(function(value) {
    var works_written;
    for (works_written in value) {
        if (value.hasOwnProperty(works_written)) {
            result[works_written] = value[works_written];
         }
     }
 });
 return result;
 };
  res = db.book.mapReduce(book, r_ja, {out: {reduce: 'joined'}})
  res = db.author.mapReduce(author, r_jp, {out: {reduce: 'joined'}})
```

can someone help me out?

Comment: join works.but i have comma separated value in works_written.how can i do this.

Comment: split function i used to count was:map = function() { 
if(this.works_written!= null)
{ 
var array = this.works_written.split(','); 
emit(this.works_written, array.length);} 
}
reduce = function(key,values) {
return values[0];
}


result = db.runCommand({
        "mapreduce" : "author", 
        "map" : map,
        "reduce" : reduce,
        "out" : "split_result"
});

Answer (score 0):

From looking at your code, it seems like you have two collections, "book" and "author".  Each book is structured as

```
{
    id: <some id>,
    name: <some name>,
    editions: <comma-separated string of editions>
}
```

and each author is structured as

```
{
    id: <some id>,
    name: <some name>,
    works_written: <comma-separated string of works written>
}
```

It would be more reasonable to store both works_written and editions as arrays rather than comma-separated lists each packed into an individual string.  This would make iterating over the array possible.

Additionally, do you have multiple documents for each author and each book?  If not, you do not need a mapreduce to do what you are attempting to do - a simple find() should work.

In case I have misinterpreted, what exactly are you attempting to do?

Comment: could u please post this as full script.no need to do anything in editions.only to comapare name[book] and work_written(author)[csv data] to emit name and edition column in book and name column in author .kindly help.